# Could you explain how this anagram function works?

Tags: java, algorithm, anagram

I have this code that I pulled off the inter net. What it does is that it checks to see if two strings are anagrams. Which basically means that they have the same amount of letters with the same kind and amount of letters. For example, "scrap" and "craps" or "hear" and "hare" . And such. Anyways, my problem is that I don't understand how it works. If anyone can give me a little insight that would be helpful! Thanks for your time guys! I  Appreciate it! Here is the code 
To be specific. I don't get the for loops part.

```js
boolean isAnagram(string s1, string s2) { 
    if (s1.length != s2.length) 
        return false; 
    char [] a1 = s1.toCharArray(); 
    char [] a2 = s2.toCharArray(); 
    for (int i = a1.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) { 
        int j; 
        for (j = a2.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) { 
            if (a1[i] == a2[j]) 
                break; 
            } 
            if (j < 0) 
                return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: This function is incorrect as it doesn’t remember the characters that were already seen: `isAnagram("aaaa", "abbb")` will falsely return `true`.

Comment: *"I have this code that I pulled off the internet"* -  This is the problem with "pulling code off the internet".  A lot of it is rubbish ... like this.  1) It doesn't work.  2) What it actually does it does in an unnecessarily obscure way.  (There is no good reason to iterate backwards, for example.)  3) The code style is bad; e.g. bad indentation, and unblocked if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code seems like a lot of work to do something simple, and it's very hard to understand it fully and verify whether it works correctly.

How about a *much* simpler approach? Sort each string character by character. Then the strings will be equal if they are anagrams of each other. You can still do the length check as an optimization, but the code will give the correct result with or without that check.

My Java is rusty, so let me give you a JavaScript version. I'm sure you can take the idea and translate it:

```
function isAnagram( s1, s2 ) {
    return(
        s1.length === s2.length  &&
        sortString(s1) === sortString(s2)
    );
}

function sortString( s ) {
    return s.split('').sort().join('');
}

function test( s1, s2, expected ) {
    var result = isAnagram( s1, s2 );
    var ok = ( result === expected ? 'OK' : '*FAIL*' );
    console.log( s1, s2, result, ok );
}

test( 'dog', 'cat', false );
test( 'bag', 'big', false );
test( 'bag', 'gab', true );
test( 'bags', 'gab', false );
test( 'foobar', 'baroof', true );
test( 'aaaa', 'abbb', false );
```

The tests give this log:

```
dog cat false OK
bag big false OK
bag gab true OK
bags gab false OK
foobar baroof true OK
aaaa abbb false OK
```

In the comments below, G. Bach raises the excellent point that other algorithms may be quite a bit faster than this one. If the task at hand is as described, to determine whether two specific strings are anagrams, then performance is unlikely to matter much if at all. Even this naive algorithm should be plenty fast.

OTOH, if you are working through a large number of strings to find out which ones are anagrams of which, then of course performance becomes more important. Even then, it can be valuable to have a simple and easily-understood implementation like this on "in the bag". For example, you could use this simple approach as part of a test case to verify your faster algorithm.

Comment: This may be simpler, but it is probably less efficient, depending on the sorting algorithm used. A histogram using an array or a hashmap should be more efficient.

Comment: That's an very good point, thanks for mentioning it. I updated the answer to talk about performance issues a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through first string, character by character in the outer loop.
Check if that character is present in the second string, this is done in the inner loop. Return false, if not present.

That's it. You need to verify though if it handles all the conditions.

Ideally, you should be able to make out this logic either by reading the code or going through it line by line using some debugger.